# how to setup embarrassingly parallel jobs on gce

Tags: google-compute-engine

what is the simplest way to setup embarrassingly parallel jobs on GCE? i have used slurm on other clusters but would like to avoid the config and installation issues. is there something available out of the box on google?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is probably not to use GCE directly!  Google Cloud has a few other products that will automatically manage config/installation of parallel soutions for you:

- [Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/), based on Apache Beam
- [Dataproc](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/), based on Hadoop
- [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/), if your query can be expressed in a SQL-like form.